# Making 3D anaglyphs with Mayavi?

Tags: python, mayavi

It's all in the title: I would like to make red-cyan anaglyphs (you know, these pictures you use coloured glasses to see in 3D) of simple shapes (like points3d plots) with Mayavi. Is there such a feature? Otherwise, would you have any advice for implementing it?

EDIT : Okay, that was simple: just hit '3' in the interactive window and this sets the stereoscopic mode on. However I'd be interested in ways to configure this option, which does not seem to be documented.

Comment: A tip I've found useful with mayavi is to use the "record" button (red ball). It opens a window with some code when you press it. Do something with the UI and the  corresponding code will show up. Then you can copy/paste the code to your script.

Comment: Will use this tip, thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Yes the interactive renderer is very poorly documented. A lot of mayavi is very badly documented, but at the least the code is often well written to figure stuff out.

Programatically you can adjust it by editing `scene.render_window.stereo_render`.

The source code of tvtk InteractiveRenderStyle has the following comment, also:

```
Some systems support crystal Eyes LCD stereo glasses; you have to invoke    
set_stereo_type_to_crystal_eyes() on the rendering window.
```

For more configuration, you'd probably have to read the tvtk source.